# wp_login.php redirects to old domain

Tags: phpmyadmin

i changed my domain name associated with my hosting account yesterday

when i click on `http://mynewdomain.com/wp_login.php` it redirects to `http://myolddomain.com`

i already changed the siteurl in phpmyadmin `wp_option` to `http://mynewdomain.com`

Comment: You need to replace all old domain name references in the database. For that use [Search and Replace Script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

Comment: did tht but now it redirects to http://mynewdomain.com doesnt show me the login page

Comment: I think, you replaced your old domain name(xyz) with [this](http://mynewdomain.com/) site's url.

Comment: Before trying any changes please keep a backup copy of the database.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change the home url (not only site url) and any other reference to the old domain in the database. To do that without breaking serialized data, you could use any of the tools receommended in the Codex's article: "[Moving WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)" in the section "Changing Your Domain Name and URLs".